# Capture Entire Error messages of Bulk Insert Command in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I have a `.csv` file & done `Bulk Insert` successfully, but in between when some values are inserted, other values are showing errors. Is it possible to capture entire error messages from that Bulk Insert command and get them inserted to ErrorLogs table for tracking purpose?

This is what I have done so far (but nothing is getting inserted to my ErrorLogs table):

```
    BEGIN TRY

    BULK INSERT Test5
    FROM 'E:\20151214.csv'
   WITH
( 
 --MAXERRORS = 0,
 FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
 ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
 DATAFILETYPE='widechar'
 );
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

     INSERT INTO ErrorLogs(ErrorDate,ErrorMessage,ErrorNumber,ErrorState,ErrorLine) SELECT 
     GetDate() as DateTimeStamp,
     ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage,
     ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
     ERROR_STATE() as ErrorState,
     ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine;

     END CATCH
    GO
```

So how am going to make Log Errors inserted into my table??

Comment: See if the final entry in this thread helps you http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1015485-149-1.aspx

Comment: @Amir - It's not working i tired it but nothing is getting inserted to my errorlog table.

Comment: @Amir - I have edited my question on what i have done so far

Comment: Do you get errors on stdout/console that you can share?

Comment: @vmachan - Bulk load: DataFileType was incorrectly specified as char. DataFileType will be assumed to be widechar because the data file has a Unicode signature. and nothing is inserted to my logtable